# Find whether string contains BOM (encoding is known)

Tags: c#-4.0, encoding

I have a string returned from a 3rd party .dll referenced in my code.
The Encoding is known, but I would like to know whether the string contains Preamble / BOM.

```
        string text = ThirdPartyDLL.GetText();
        string encoding = ThirdPartyDLL.GetEncodingName();

        bool hasPreamble = ?
```

Comment: Encoding plays no role, strings are always utf-16 in .NET.  Having that DLL get that wrong is an unfixable problem on your end.  It not filtering out the BOM is already a big red flag.  bool hasPreamble = text.StartsWith("\ufeff")

Comment: Thanks @Hans. When I get byte[] from the string first two elements are indeed 255 254. Will it always be FFFE? My Encoding.Default is System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding in case that helps

Comment: If you get two elements then it did not decode the string properly.  You should try Encoding.Unicode next.